# Force Google Chrome to use IPv4 for localhost

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ip

I have tried every suggestion that I found on stackoverflow, such as:

- put '127.0.0.1 localhost' to hosts file
- set DisabledComponents=0x20
  for
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TCPIP6\Parameters
- netsh interface ipv6 add prefixpolicy

but Google Chrome (Version 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit)) still uses IPv6 for localhost (tested on Windows 7 and Windows 10).

Is there anything else, that I can do to force Chrome use IPv4 for localhost
?

Comment: Put some other name into hosts file and use that instead of localhost